# str2num dialoge box matlab in GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm trying to right this peice of code where the user would input values for a and for b but b has to be bigger then a. So the code would test it and in case of an error reply with a dialogue box asking the user which value does he wants to re-enter, the user would click on a push button that should lead him to another dialogue box that should ask him for the value of the either a or b, and then check this new value entered. I need those values to come out as numbers for some later calculations but i can't get my code working, here is what i have so far:

```
if str2num(b) <= str2num(a); %convert value to doulbe to run the test
    promptMessage = sprintf('The value of the b is smaller or equal to the value of a,     do you want to reinput the value of the a or the value of the b?' );
    button = questdlg(promptMessage, 'Reinput value of a or b ?', 'a', 'b', 'Rod-Crank'); 
    if strcmpi(button, 'a')
        prompt = ('Please reenter the value of a:');
        a=inputdlg(prompt);
        while isnan(str2double(a)) || ~isreal(str2double(a)) || isinf(str2double(a)) ||  str2double(a) <= 0;
            prompt = ('Please reenter the value of a:');
            a=inputdlg(prompt); 
        end
    c = char(a);
    a=str2num(c(1));
    b=str2num(b);

    end
    if strcmpi(button, 'b')
        prompt = ('Please reenter the value of b:');
        b=inputdlg(prompt);
        while isnan(str2double(b)) || ~isreal(str2double(b)) || isinf(str2double(b)) || str2double (b) <= 0;
            prompt = ('Please reenter the value of b:');
            b=inputdlg(prompt); 
        end
     c = char(b);
    b=str2num(c(1));
    a=str2num(a); 
    end
end   
 if isnan(str2double(f)) || ~isreal(str2double(f)) || isinf(str2double(f)) || isempty(f) || str2double (f) < 0; % test if the value of c is valid
     promptMessage = sprintf('The value entered for the Frequency " %0.5g " is incorrect, Please reenter the value for Frequency ', f);
     button = questdlg(promptMessage, 'Error in value of the Frequency.', 'Ok', 'Ok');
end
f = str2num(f);




for t = 0 : 1 : 360;
    Time = t+1;
    O = (2.*pi.*f)./60;
    i = b.^2-a.^2.*((sind(t)).^2);
    j = (a.^2).*(O).*sind(2.*t);

    dt (Time) = a.*cosd(t)+ sqrt(i);
    V (Time) = (-a.*O.*sind(t))-(j/(2.*(sqrt(i))));
    A (Time) = (-a.*(O.^2).*cosd(t))-(4.*(a.^2).*(O.^2).*cosd(2.*t).*i + j.^2)/(4.*(i.^1.5));
    y (Time) = t;
end
```

Comment: what error-message do you get?

Comment: In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Error in untitled>button1_Callback (line 168)
        dt (Time) = a.*cosd(t)+ sqrt(i);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in untitled (line 17)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)untitled('button1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

 
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback